# How to customize a navigation controller in swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I'm trying to customize the navigation controller, but it's not working

I think this because i'm using the app delegate to move from a view to another with this code :

```
let mainStoryboardIpad : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let initialViewControlleripad : UIViewController = mainStoryboardIpad.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("HomeView") as! ViewControllerHome
    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
    self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewControlleripad
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

My storyboard

[image: My story board]

I'm changing the title with the storyboard or programmatically it doesn't work, and I don't see the title changing

```
self.navigationController?.title="Mytitle"
```

Comment: use `self.title="title"` in viewdidload of viewcontroller

Comment: That works, but how to change the color of the title in that case

Comment: I'm trying this  self.navigationController?.navigationItem.titleView?.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor() but it's not working

Comment: Thanks for your help but it's not working

Answer (score 0):

You should change the title of the view controller inside the navigation controller, rather than the navigation controller itself.

Comment: Can you give an example please I don't understand what do you mean